# How get DateTime Format on PHP: 2016-01-29T09:29:29.5033083+03:00

Tags: php, datetime, formatdatetime

Who can say that over time, the date format is used here?

```
<Date>2016-01-29T09:29:29.5033083+03:00</Date>
```

I tried to do it on php$time = microtime();

```
list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", $time);
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimestamp($time);
$usec = $usec * 1000000;
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.'.$usec.'P') . "<hr>";
```

Result:

```
 2016-05-19T12:52:04.415507+05:00
```

But the number of characters is not the same:

```
.5033083
.415507
```

How do I get this format to php?

```
<Date>2016-01-29T09:29:29.5033083+03:00</Date>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
//prints something like: 2000-07-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

helping links are
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: Where in your decision to answer my question?

Comment: I asked:
1. Who can say that over time, the date format is used here? 2. What kind of numbers .5033083, and how to get them?